# Reason for Could not load or find assemble

Tags: c#, dll

I just generated a 32-bit dll from a library and am trying to use it with my windows based form application in C# (debug - x86). I added the dll file as a reference and now when I run the code I get the following error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'org.apache.qpid.messaging.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
  Source=QpidRx_CSharp
  FileName=org.apache.qpid.messaging.dll
  FusionLog=""
  StackTrace:
       at QpidRx_CSharp.Program.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Any suggetsions on how I might resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the dll with the (free and excellent) ['DependencyWalker'](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what's missing (since the error seems to indicate that's the exact problem here: you are not fulfilling all needed dependencies).

Comment: @ChristopherD thanks a lot.. The DependencyWalker solved my issue!!

Answer (score 1):

Is the `Copy Local` value set to True on the DLL reference for the project that is consuming the DLL? (right-click the reference in the Solution Explorer in VS, and select properties). If not, then the DLL won't be in the app's Bin\Debug folder and it won't be found.

Another possibility is that your DLL itself has dependencies which can't be found. Does your DLL reference anything other than .Net framework assemblies?

Comment: How do I find out whether the dll references other assemblies ?

Comment: I inferred from your post that the error was being thrown by your app because it couldn't find the DLL. But I see now that the error is being thrown by the DLL not your app. Perhaps your problem issimilar to the one described here http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/Building-Net-Projects-td5323082.html

Comment: I used the dependencywalker application it turns out it required other libraries too